# When is a return type not exactly a return type? (template specialization, "auto")

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, auto

TL;DR - Why does it seem my one method isn't returning the type it says it does and thus causes issues with my specialized template methods?

This is a case of I'm not 100% sure what I'm dealing with, so I'm not sure how to title the question properly.  I have two classes... `Union32` is a class which provides endian-correct access to portions of a multi-byte/multi-word scalar (the class here has been chopped down for example purposes).  The class contains a couple of template methods, `Get()` and `Set()`, and specializations of each are provided.

`Modbus32` is a template class for a 32-bit scalar stored in a Modbus register file; Modbus registers are 16-bit, so concatenating two permits storing/accessing 32-bit values.  But since Modbus is a big-endian protocol (16-bit registers are transmitted MSB first), you almost certainly want to store the most-significant word first; `Modbus32` encapsulates that behavior and uses `Union32` to re-assemble the 32-bit value according to the machine's endianness.

`Modbus32` also has `Get()` and `Set()` methods, along with a `GetUnion()` method which returns a `Union32` object assembled from the `uint16_t msw` and `uint16_t lsw` class members.  The parameter to the `Modbus32` template is a 32-bit typename (e.g. `uint32_t`, `int32_t`), and this typename (`ValueType`) is used to govern which specialized `Union32::Get()` method is called when returning the value of the 32-bit Modbus register.

Anyway, to the example, and the errors I encountered while trying to create `Modbus32::Get()` ([link to example hosted on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d4a0ba5bf8110e4), using C++14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

#define INDUCE_COMPILER_ERRORS   0   // Set to 1 to see the compiler errors.

/* Container for 32-bit data, allows endian-correct access to bytes/words. */
class Union32 {
 public:
  Union32() { value = 0; }
  explicit Union32(uint16_t msw, uint16_t lsw) {
    endian_word.lsw = lsw;
    endian_word.msw = msw;
  }
  static constexpr size_t kLength = 4;
  template<typename ValueType> ValueType Get(void) const;
  template<typename ValueType> void Set(ValueType set_value);
  /* Machine is little endian. */
  struct endian_word_t {
    uint16_t lsw;           // Least-significant word.
    uint16_t msw;           // Most-significant word.
  };
  union {
    uint32_t value;             // Integer value.
    int32_t signed_value;       // Signed integer value.
    endian_word_t endian_word;  // Least/most significant 16-bit words.
  };
};

/* Specializations for Union32::Get(). */
template<> inline int32_t Union32::Get<int32_t>(void) const { return signed_value; }
template<> inline uint32_t Union32::Get<uint32_t>(void) const { return value; }
template<> inline void Union32::Set<int32_t>(int32_t set_value) { signed_value = set_value; }
template<> inline void Union32::Set<uint32_t>(uint32_t set_value) { value = set_value; }

/* Class that explicitly stores MSW first in memory, a la Modbus. */
template<typename ValueType,
    class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<ValueType>::value>::type,
    class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(ValueType) == sizeof(uint32_t)>::type>
struct Modbus32 {
  uint16_t msw;       // Most significant word.
  uint16_t lsw;       // Least significant word.
  inline Union32 GetUnion(void) const {
    return Union32(msw, lsw);  // Creates a Union32 object from the MSW and LSW.
  }
  inline ValueType Get_Working1(void) const {
    Union32 u32 = GetUnion();
    return u32.Get<ValueType>();
  }
  inline ValueType Get_Broken1(void) const {
    /* Error: no matching function for call to 'Union32::Get()' */
    /* Only generates an error when called by conversion operator. */
    return GetUnion().Get();
  }
#if INDUCE_COMPILER_ERRORS   // Set to 1 to see the compiler errors.
  inline ValueType Get_Broken2(void) const {
    /* Error: expected primary-expression before '>' token */
    return GetUnion().Get<ValueType>(); // doesn't like the explicit template parameter, I guess?
  }
  inline ValueType Get_Broken3(void) const {
    auto u32 = GetUnion();
    /* Error: expected primary-expression before '>' token */
    return u32.Get<ValueType>(); // only difference from Get_Working1() is "Union32" vs. "auto"
  }
#endif
  inline operator ValueType() const {
    /* Call one of the above Get() methods here. */
    return Get_Working1();
    //return Get_Broken1();  // will cause compiler error when invoked
  }
};

typedef Modbus32<uint32_t> ModbusUint32;
typedef Modbus32<int32_t> ModbusInt32;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from GCC " __VERSION__ "!" << std::endl;
    ModbusUint32 foo32;
    foo32.msw = 2;             // Returns 2*65536 + 1*1 = 131073
    foo32.lsw = 1;
    uint32_t value = foo32;    // Calls the implicit conversion operator.
    std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have found exactly one way to compose the `Get()` method such that the compiler likes it, namely `Get_Working1()`.  This method declares a local `Union32 u32` and assigns it the result of the `GetUnion()` method, then in the next statement it returns the value `u32.Get<ValueType>()`.  That seems pretty straightforward.

However, I've found three different ways to break that working example, using methods `Get_Broken1/2/3()`.  `Get_Broken1()` may be a red herring, as I would expect template argument deduction shouldn't work here, so probably ignore that one for now.  But the other two don't make sense to me, and I have a suspicion it comes down to the return type (or possibly rvalue/lvalue-ness) of `GetUnion()`.

`Get_Broken2()` takes the working method and removes the `u32` local variable (an lvalue), using `GetUnion()` as an rvalue instead.  `Get_Broken3()` changes even less, only substituting `auto` for `Union32` when declaring `u32`.  And yet both of these methods break the compiler (expects primary expression, etc), despite appearing to be functionally equivalent to `Get_Working1()`.

The return type for `GetUnion()` is `Union32`.  So why can't I call `GetUnion().Get<ValueType>()` without protest?  I thought maybe it was an lvalue/rvalue thing, but the third example I think disproves that and tells me that there's something else going on.  In `Get_Broken3()`, how does `auto u32 = GetUnion();` *not* result in `u32` being of type `Union32`?  Why does it matter if `u32` is explicitly declared to be `Union32` instead of automatically?  How could `u32` be anything other than `Union32`?

In summary, I have working code in `Get_Working1()`, and while I've managed to break the compiler with three different examples, I think `Get_Broken3()` probably exposes the true root of the issue.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what that is.  If someone can shed some light on this, that would be tremendous, thanks.

Comment: This question is very well asked. However, it is a bit broad since you're asking 3 questions, making it difficult to answer this as a single question unless the 3 questions are directly related. Consider narrowing down the question to focus on just a single question.

Comment: @cigien et al - Thanks for the feedback and edits (relative SO newb here).  I'll try to rephrase my question to make it one question, since I have a feeling that cases 2 and 3 are directly related to the return type of `GetUnion()`, and case 1 is probably unimportant once you solve that first mystery.

Comment: I like your edits. They're minimal edits, the question still describe the research you've done, and it is now basically asking a single question. Well done :)

Comment: Your question and code are very long. Not many people would read that much text without knowing first if it look interesting! Presentation is very important!

Comment: The compiler error messages, while you don't understand them, would save someone who does understand them the time to make your code build and reproduce them.  Post them with a `>` followed by 6 spaces (5 might also work) to generate "quoted code" (might need a `>` on each line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both gcc and clang think that the return value of `GetUnion` is dependent onnthe type parameters of Modbus.  I don;t know why.

To fix the compile error, add `template` before `Get`.

Because `GetUnion().Get` is being parsed as if `Get` was a value in the struct returned from `GetUnion()`.

In the working example, `Union32 x=GetUnion();`, the type of `x` is not considered dependent on the template arguments.  It is `Union32`.

I am uncertain why the compilers consider the return type of a method with a fixed return type as dependent on the template parameters within the body of the class definition.  It might just be a slightly screwed up standard C++ rule.

So, try:

```
return GetUnion().template Get<ValueType>();
```

Comment: Well, you've sussed out the actual fix, using `template` in the invocation of `Get<type>()`.  That works in my original non-redacted production code.  Should I ask another question that narrows in on why `template` is required in this context?  Or do some major editing on this existing question?  I'm leaning to the latter.  Opinions?  @cigien ?

Comment: @DavidR Well, it is the return value of `this->Method()`, which (barring some wording excluding it) seems dependent on the template parameters of `this`, and hence a dependent type.  Which you then `.TemplateMethod<X>()`.